# why can I use stdio.h without a corresponding stdio.c

Tags: c, include, header-files

When I write a multi module program in c, i use header files for function prototypes and the like, connect things with #includes (using "" not <>), and when i come to compile I compile the .c files together:

```
gcc foo.c bar.c -o name
```

When i include `stdlib.h` for example, i do not need to compile a corresponding .c file. so where do the definitions of all the functions in stdlib come from? is there code in the `header`? do compilers treat <> headers specially? could I (theoretically) write a header which worked like stdio, stdlib, etc?

Comment: the code behind standard libraries is added at link time. I think there' s a duplicate of that question somewhere.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Suggested one

Comment: @SouravGhosh nice find.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Disclaimer: one of the answers is mine. :)

Comment: nice one. Links to duplicate are not upvoted often enough (well apart from the ones with 2547 upvotes for `exit(0);` :)

Comment: btw the `<>` vs `""` bit hasn't been answered. It's just a search convention: current dir isn't searched when you specify `<>`.